# sql update multiple columns with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I want to update 5 columns from another table.  2 of the column will be up dated from a condition the other 3 will also be update if condition one is true and condition two is true.  is there a way to do this in one statement?

```
update tableNew
set 
column1 = t1.column1
column2 = t1.column2

column3 = t1.column3
column4 = t1.column4
column5 = t1.column5
where t1.column10 in ('value1','value2') 

from tableOld t1
where t1.column8 is null
```

i hope you can understand what I need from this example if not I can try and give more!!

Comment: For what database?  MySQL and SQL Server support JOINs in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: You can specify `WHERE t1.column10 IN ('value1', 'value2') AND t1.column8 IS NULL` as a single condition; you're then just left with sorting out the join update notation.

Comment: SQL Server... I need the updates to be nested because three of the five column will be updated if both conditions are true where only one has to be true to update the other three